# Are new paradigms of programming always driven by a need?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm something of a programming language junkie, and examples abound...

- Lisp was originally created as a practical mathematical notation for computer programs
- Simula was designed for doing simulations, and gave us objects and classes
- C was designed for implementing system software (specifically, the Unix operating system)
- Erlang was designed with the aim of improving the development of telephony applications at Ericsson.

Languages like Perl and Ruby also, but these four gave birth to fundamental styles of computer programming, as opposed to "just" implementing an existing methodology or style of solving specific software engineering problems.

Is every new [programming paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) primarily driven by a need to solve a practical problem? Does every new programming language come about from a programmer scratching an itch?

As I plan to dedicate my life to research in new programming languages for AI, I'm wondering whether I should pursue the theory of programming intelligence directly, or attempt to solve practical problems in AI and then "discover" the paradigms to solve them.

Comment: You're quite mistaken about c "giving birth to a fundamental style": at the time it was written it was just another imperative language that supported structured programming (compare with algo, B, pascal, ...). Why c in particular was so successful is an interesting issue, but not really in the scope of SO.

Comment: Also, this "question" is explicitly a discussion topic, so not SO fodder either.

Comment: @dmckee has a good point. Strictly speaking, C wasn't really new - there were kind-of-highlevel languages in the 60s. Still C was (one of ..., I guess) the first language(s) suitable for system programming that was really platformindependent. Well, became available on many platforms later on.

Comment: The question can be answered "yes" or "no", so not  a discussion.

Comment: @Neil Either answer calls for a good sized essay to defend it, taking multiple examples from history and dissecting the ideas of what constitutes "programming paradigm" and "new". You can say "yes" or "no" but the answers will be decidedly unhelpful, or you can discuss the topic at length.

Comment: @dmckee Well, the current answers are certainly not essay length, and I didn't realise that length was  a factor in judging answers anyway. By your reasoning, a C++ question like "should I use pointers or references" would also not "really be in the scope of SO".

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I think by that logic you could argue that any question is not a discussion, just by picking an answer.

Comment: `@dmckee:` After all this time, the C programming language is still the best representation we have of an abstract machine.

Answer (score 2):

No, most are.  But you're forgetting Esoteric programming languages.

Example: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html

A language that uses JPG's as code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that every language is designed according to some need. That need of course can just be the language designers own desire for a more elegant language, a language he himself feels more comfortable programming in.

However, the language that are successful will very likely provide some solutions to a more general need. This need my not necesarely be evident at the time the language is designed, but for it to get recognition I think it has to be a need that is shared and gets shelved out as a general desire at some point.

There are probably a lot of languages out there that did not necessarely address a problem that is shared by many others or maybe even adresses needs that have not been wiledly realized as such.

To you concrete question: I think the best way to discover the shortcomings of current languages is to use them. Of course, the theory may help you to come up with appropriate solutions. So I'd say the best way is (as always) to have theoretical knowledge and practical experience.

Answer (score 0):

You'd think nobody would invest time in inventing, refining, implementing, using and spreading a new way of doing things if "the old ways" worked just fine. And the real world, as in your examples, confirms this theory. All this still applies if we broaden the scope beyond programming paradigms. So I'd say it is safe to assume inventions are (partly) driven by a need for the thing invented.

*hits his smartass alter ego with a bat and takes over the talk*

As for the question in the last paragraph: If anyone knows whether you'll have more fun pursuing theory or solving real problems, it's you. **I** would choose practice any time of the day - but I'm not you. But from looking at (programming language) history I can tell that all no great (i.e. can be used to get things done) language came from theory. It is logical to assume one can't find a good tool for an application without knowing that application throughoutly from daily work.